# Trouble installing Python Pip on MacOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am very new to coding and the like. For some background, I am trying to install a plugin that will allow me to use mod organizer 2 with OpenMW (An engine that runs the game Morrowind) on MacOS. When I tried to use this plugin, it said I needed to install a module called PyQt5. I asked Bing's Copilot what to do and it said to use python's pip to install it. When I tried, it said Pip Command Not Found, so I tried reinstalling python, but whenever I try to check if pip is installed, it gives me this error:

```
charliesampler@Charlies-MacBook-Pro ~ % pip3 --version]
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = '/usr/local/bin/python3.9'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/local/bin/python3.9'
  sys.base_prefix = '/usr/local'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/usr/local'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = '/usr/local/bin/python3.9'
  sys.prefix = '/usr/local'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/usr/local'
  sys.path = [
    '/usr/local/lib/python39.zip',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.9',
    '/usr/local/lib/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00000002047cc240 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

I originally tried setting the PythonPath and PythonHome to my user files but then I read on this site that I shouldn't do that. So I unset both PythonPath and PythonHome but whenever I try to check if Pip is working it still gives me the error.

Comment: Insufficient information and things that make no sense. For example, you don't tell us how you "tried reinstalling python". The closing bracket in `pip3 --version]` makes no sense. Given the */usr/local/bin* paths I'm guessing you are using `brew install python` but I shouldn't have to guess. Note that MacOS ships with a version of Python. If you're also installing Python using HomeBrew you need to make sure your `PATH` is setup to use the version of the commands you want. What does `which -a pip3` and `which -a python3` output?

Comment: Also, if you Google "Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding" you'll find documents like https://discuss.python.org/t/fatal-python-error-init-fs-encoding-failed-to-get-the-python-codec-of-the-filesystem-encoding/3173 which implies you are still setting `PYTHONHOME` and/or `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: @Kurtis I apologize for the confusion, I'm not yet used to asking specific questions like this so I ask that you bear with me. I did install python via Homebrew, but I think that I installed multiple versions of it on accident. When I type in the command `which -a pip3` it gives me this: `charliesampler@Charlies-MacBook-Pro ~ % which -a pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3
/opt/homebrew/bin/pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3
/usr/bin/pip3
charliesampler@Charlies-MacBook-Pro ~ % `

Comment: Executing `which -a pip3` should not list the same path multiple times. That it does means you have */usr/local/bin* in your `PATH` env var multiple times. Which is normally harmless but suggests you are digging yourself into a deep hole by making changes to your shell config without understanding what you are doing. You should also provide such information by updating your original question rather than in a comment. You also did not address my point that the "Fatal Python error" implies you still are setting `PYTHONHOME` and/or `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: I'll also point out it is not unusual for HomeBrew to install multiple Python versions to satisfy the dependencies of other HomeBrew packages you you installed. That, however, should not be an issue for you since a path like */usr/local/bin/python3* will always be to a specific version (usually the most recent) so that any older Python version installed to satisfy the dependency on Python by that version won't affect your use of `python3` or `pip3`.

Comment: @kurtis So what do I do to fix it? I'm not fully understanding. Also in the same error code that I posted here says that my `PYTHONHOME` and `PYTHONPATH` are not set because I unset them previously.

Comment: Did you confirm those env vars are not set? What does `echo $PYTHONHOME $PYTHONPATH` output? You might also want to run `env | grep PYTHON` to see if you have any Python env vars set.

Comment: @kurtis I put in the commands you gave and they both gave this: `echo $PYTHONHOME $PYTHONPATH
/usr/local /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands`

Comment: @kurtis There is a word limit but here is the second one: `env | grep PYTHON
PYTHONHOME=/usr/local
PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands`

Comment: Again, put that information in the original question, not followup comments. Also, isn't it obvious you still have both env vars set? You said in your question that you unset them.